# Linq query to group by field1, count field2 and filter by count between values of joined collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm having trouble with getting a my linq query correct. I've been resisting doing this with foreach loops because I'm trying to better understand linq.

I have following data in LinqPad.

```
void Main()
{
    var events = new[] {
        new {ID = 1, EventLevel = 1, PatientID = "1", CodeID = "2", Occurences = 0 },
        new {ID = 2, EventLevel = 2, PatientID = "1", CodeID = "2", Occurences = 0 },
        new {ID = 3, EventLevel = 1, PatientID = "2", CodeID = "1", Occurences = 0 },
        new {ID = 4, EventLevel = 3, PatientID = "2", CodeID = "2", Occurences = 0 },
        new {ID = 5, EventLevel = 1, PatientID = "3", CodeID = "3", Occurences = 0 },
        new {ID = 6, EventLevel = 3, PatientID = "1", CodeID = "4", Occurences = 0 }
    };

    var filter = new FilterCriterion();
    var searches = new List<FilterCriterion.Occurence>();
    searches.Add(new FilterCriterion.Occurence() { CodeID = "1", MinOccurences = 2, MaxOccurences = 3 });
    searches.Add(new FilterCriterion.Occurence() { CodeID = "2", MinOccurences = 2, MaxOccurences = 3 });

    filter.Searches = searches;

    var summary = from e in events
        let de = new
        {
            PatientID = e.PatientID,
            CodeID = e.CodeID
        }
        group e by de into t
        select new
        {
            PatientID = t.Key.PatientID,
                CodeID = t.Key.CodeID,
            Occurences = t.Count(d => t.Key.CodeID == d.CodeID)
        };

    var allCodes = filter.Searches.Select(i => i.CodeID);

    summary = summary.Where(e => allCodes.Contains(e.CodeID));

    // How do I find the original ID property from the "events" collection and how do I 
    // eliminate the instances where the Occurences is not between MinOccurences and MaxOccurences.

    foreach (var item in summary)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}

public class FilterCriterion
{

   public IEnumerable<Occurence> Searches { get; set; }

   public class Occurence
   {
       public string CodeID { get; set; }
       public int? MinOccurences { get; set; }
       public int? MaxOccurences { get; set; }
   }

}
```

The problem I have is that need to filter the results by the MinOccurences and MaxOccurences filter property and in the end I want the "events" objects where the IDs are 1,2,3 and 4.

Thanks in advance if you can provide help.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question - maybe desired output as an example would help

Comment: Why ids `3` and `4`? They don't seem to fit within min-max occurrences.

Comment: My mistake. You are correct. I should only be getting back IDs 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `event.ID` at the end of processing you need to pass it with your first query. Alter `select` to this:

```
// ...
group e by de into t
select new
{
    PatientID = t.Key.PatientID,
    CodeID = t.Key.CodeID,
    Occurences = t.Count(d => t.Key.CodeID == d.CodeID),
    // taking original items with us
    Items = t
};
```

Having done that, your final query (including occurrences filter) *might* look like this:

```
var result = summary
    // get all necessary data, including filter that matched given item
    .Select(Item => new
        {
            Item,
            Filter = searches.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CodeID == Item.CodeID)
        })
    // get rid of those without matching filter
    .Where(i => i.Filter != null)
    // this is your occurrences filtering
    .Where(i => i.Item.Occurences >= i.Filter.MinOccurences
        && i.Item.Occurences <= i.Filter.MaxOccurences)
    // and finally extract original events IDs
    .SelectMany(i => i.Item.Items)
    .Select(i => i.ID);
```

This produces `1`, `2` as result. `3` and `4` are left out as they don't get past occurrences filtering.

Comment: Oh, I see it now thanks to your excellent explanation. I didn't realize I could take the entire set of original items along. You're doing a similar thing with the anonymous object in the Select statement where you're passing the filter object and then chaining Where clauses to prevent null object exceptions. This is really cool. Thanks so much for your help. I understand it a little better now.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your program in linqpad.

My understanding is that you want to filter using filter.MinOccurences and filter.MaxOccurences on Occurences count of result data set.

You can add additional filters using Where clause.

```
if (filter.MinOccurences.HasValue)
 summary = summary.Where (x=> x.Occurences >= filter.MinOccurences);

if (filter.MaxOccurences.HasValue)
 summary = summary.Where (x=> x.Occurences <= filter.MaxOccurences);
```